# How do I force players off a rail when dismounting a minecart?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-redstone

I am creating a transport rail system (mini metro) for players in Minecraft Bedrock Edition. The minecart are perpetually in a one-way motion due to powered rails along the track. Each station has a dismounting area where players can dismount from their minecart before continuing on to the mounting area where players can board empty minecarts. Both areas use rapidly flashing powered rails to slow the minecarts down so players have a few seconds to board/dismount.

When dismounting from a moving minecart, or when ejected from an active activator rail, the player is deposited directly above the rail on which the minecart is on. If the player does not move off the tracks manually before the next minecart comes, the minecart will bump into them and stop, causing delays on the metro line. The minecart that they dismounted from will not be affected, so it is not a problem.
[image: First Attempt]
The picture above depicts my first attempt at solving this problem. The pistons with glass are on a hopper clock circuit, and the powered rails are rapidly pulsing at the rate of a [comparator subtraction clock](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Mechanics/Redstone/Clock_circuit#Subtraction_clock), as explained above. The water and hole are where the players fall when pushed by the pistons, falling into a safe landing and funneled to the station exit.

However, I frown upon this solution because it is very noisy with the pistons constantly firing. To attempt to fix this, I changed the setup so that there was only one piston pushing five slime blocks which are connected to the glass. However, this solution is still noisy because piston sound volume does not stack in Bedrock Edition.

What is the best way to automatically maneuver players off the track quickly without causing too much noise?

Comment: "When dismounting from a moving minecart, or when ejected from an active activator rail, the player is deposited directly above the rail on which the minecart is on." That is not supposed to happen. You should report it on the bug tracker, if it hasn't been already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When players dismount from a minecart, it is true that they stay on the same x and z position, but they are deposited about half a block above the rail. You can therefore place a tripwire above the rail, and it will be tripped whenever a player dismounts.

[image: Front View]
[image: Rear View]

### Notes

- Place the tripwire hooks one block out from the pistons. These blocks do not count for detection of players.
- Use a transparent block like glass, unless you want others on the rail line to suffocate when the pistons are activated from a different player.